# Got 200 FTP reply code but file not sent

Tags: java, tls1.2, ftps

Ive got a little problem which slowly makes me frustrated. I need to send file to FTP server over TLS, using *org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient* and got a 200 reply code after calling *storeFile()* method but i don't see any result on a server.

FTP server is not running on my local host. When I do the same thing but using a Filezilla client then it's all done without any problems in both passive and active modes.

```
FTPSClient ftpsClient = new FTPSClient("TLS", false);

        ftpsClient.connect(server, port);

        boolean logged = ftpsClient.login(user, pass);
        ftpsClient.enterRemotePassiveMode();
        System.out.println(ftpsClient.getReplyCode());

        ftpsClient.execPBSZ(0);
        ftpsClient.execPROT("P");

        ftpsClient.sendCommand("TYPE", "A");
        System.out.println(ftpsClient.getReplyCode());

        File file = new File("config.xml");
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        boolean done = ftpsClient.storeFile("config.xml", inputStream);
        System.out.println(ftpsClient.getReplyCode());

        inputStream.close();
```

result of this code execution is:

227

200

200

But maybe this STOR command hasn't overed in fact and this 200 code is related to command before?

Answer (score 0):

If somebody is interested in solution of this problem, it was about resuming ssl session which was required by server and not handled by client. After unselecting this option on filezilla server it has started to work properly.